# Chinese Idiom puzzle 19 (中文填字遊戲)

Tags: idioms, games, puzzle

Another puzzle for May-2021

[image]

1. One of the three dynasties in the Three Kingdoms period ruled by the 曹 family
2. A poem that was written by Cao Zhi (曹植). Fictionalized the author's encounter with a goddess  and their love
3. Extremely urgent
4. 全真派始創人
5. 相傳關羽曾接受( )( )療毒
6. Withdraw bravely from the rapid current. It is a metaphor for people who are able to retreat in a timely manner
7. Only good at theoretical military talks, but can’t actually use them on the battlefield
8. A mother's status raises because of her son's birth or her son's success
9. A Strategy/ plot comes into mind
10. 輕於鴻毛的相反
11. 太極拳其中一個要旨  (borrow force to counter force)
12. Executioner
13. Do one's best
14. Do it yourself
15. Make the same mistake
16. Tender love like water
17. Vividly like in front of one's eyes
18. In a dark place, with no sunlight
19. To remedy
20. Very touching
21. Craftsman
22. Understand
23. Once in a lifetime chance
24. (Send troops to fight the guilty) -- to announce the crimes of others and severely condemned them )
25. Run into good luck
26. Legalism
27. The Great Wall

A. Be the model for all mothers -- description of a queen's duty

B. Good as new, not become old and obsolete after a long period of time

C. 11:00 PM - 1:00 AM

D. 曹操的爵位

E. When a son wanted to support his parents, they have already passed away

F. Ingenious craftsmanship

G. A literary work becomes popular and spreads far and wide

H. Arrogant and despise others

I. Do things according to one's own strength

J. Join the good guys

K. Conscription

L. Build a business from the ground up by yourself

M. Strategies and strength are exhausted

N. See the sky and the sun again (out of the darkness)

O. A name of the beheading sentence in ancient times

P. Deep memory, unforgettable

Q. Entire army is completely annihilated

R. "A man is not guilty" --「懷璧其罪」上句

S. Tens of thousands (a great number of)

T. (Affairs can be classified as) Deferrable or urgent, unimportant or important

U. Soft

V. Not attacking with the intention of causing serious harm (not be too harsh on someone)

W. Force someone to do something that he couldn't do

X. Heroic; brave

Y. 曹操「短歌行」其中兩句 (Mountains don't mind being high, water doesn't mind being deep)

Answer (score 1):

Corrected according to Tang Ho's comment.

1. 曹魏
2. 洛神赋
3. 刻不容缓
4. 王重阳
5. 刮骨
6. 急流勇退
7. 纸上谈兵
8. 母凭子贵
9. 计上心头
10. 重于泰山
11. 借力打力
12. 刽子手
13. 竭尽全力
14. 亲力亲为
15. 重蹈覆辙
16. 柔情似水
17. 历历在目
18. 暗无天日
19. 弥补
20. 感人至深
21. 匠人
22. 明白
23. 千载难逢
24. 兴师问罪
25. 时来运转
26. 法家
27. 万里长城

A. 母仪天下

B. 历久弥新

C. 子时

D. 魏王

E. 子欲养而亲不在

F. 匠心独运

G. 洛阳纸贵

H. 目中无人

I. 量力而行

J. 弃暗投明

K. 征兵

L. 白手兴家

M. 计穷力竭

N. 重见天日

O. 问斩

P. 刻骨铭心

Q. 全军覆没

R. 匹夫无罪

S. 千千万万

T. 缓急轻重

U. 柔软

V. 手下留情

W. 强人所难

X. 英勇

Y. 山不厌高，水不厌深

Some notes:

8. Not an idiom. It is a four-character word coined in a costume drama. (According to Tang Ho it is a common expression.)

E. The original text in 韩诗外传 should be 子欲养而亲不**待**也.

J. It means 'leave the reactionary camp and cross over to the side of progress'. Often used to describe someone leaves the enemy and joins (surrenders to) 'us' (from the narrator's point of view).

L. For me 白手起家 is more often heard. 白手兴家 seems to be Cantonese. Here it can only be 白手兴家, for in question 16 起师问罪 is used very seldom (it is even not in an idiom dictionary).

O. I think it should be understood as 'sentence to (问) capital penalty (斩)'.

T. 轻重缓急 is more often heard.

Y. Another version gives 海不厌深. Here it can only be 水不厌深 due to question 16.

Comment: 1. 曹魏 5. 刮骨 14. 親力親為 C.子時 D.魏王 I.量力而為.

Comment: Note: 8. 母凭子贵 is not an idiom, but a common expression. Y. 海不厌深 (variant 水不厌深), I checked